# NFC between two different applications Android

Tags: android

I new at NFC with Android, and I am beginning to develop apps using NFC to communicate each other.

By now, what I was doing is communication between the same Activity and so on.
Well, now, I would like to see if it is possible to communicate TWO DIFFERENT APPS through NFC.

So, is it possible to communicate using NFC between two different apps (that I develop) ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You simply set the mime type in your manifest file and in your NDEF message (in the createNdefMessage method) as follows:

createNdefMessage:

```
NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { createMimeRecord( yourMimeType,payloadByteArray)});
```

Manifest:

```
<data android:mimeType="yourMimeType" />
```

This way, any nfc intents will be handled by the applications.

Comment: Ok, and.....how to send the Message??? Which method should I use? "enableForegroundDispatch", "enableForegroundNdefPush"?? Btw, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Ok, I was sending the message between two different activities. And now, I have one problem.......can I make it before API 16?? Cause the NdefRecord.createMimeRecord() method is only working for API 16 and after......is there a way to do it for API 14??? Thanks a lot! U were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

the createMimeRecord() method should be implemented by you and should return an NdefRecord. You can replace it with an object of type NdefRecord like so:

```
NdefRecord mime = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, mimeTypeByteArray, new byte[0], payloadByteArray);
```

In this case, use mime instead of createMimeRecord().